# SSRS Multiple page for each DataSet's row

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2008-r2

Ciao, this is my scenario.

I'm building a Report with SQL Server Reporting Services.

I have two DataSet:

- Continent
- Countries

And I build a report like that:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | Continent |
+----+-----------+
| 01 | Europa    |
+----+-----------+

+----+-------------+
| ID | Countries   |
+----+-------------+
| 01 | Italia      |
+----+-------------+
| 02 | Switzerland |
+----+-------------+
| 03 | Germany     |
+----+-------------+
| 04 | Etc.        |
+----+-------------+
```

My report work good for one page. Now I would generate multiple pages like that:

```
Page 1
+----+-----------+
| ID | Continent |
+----+-----------+
| 01 | Europa    |
+----+-----------+

+----+-------------+
| ID | Countries   |
+----+-------------+
| 01 | Italia      |
+----+-------------+
| 02 | Switzerland |
+----+-------------+
| 03 | Germany     |
+----+-------------+

Page 2
+----+-----------+
| ID | Continent |
+----+-----------+
| 01 | America   |
+----+-----------+

+----+-------------+
| ID | Countries   |
+----+-------------+
| 01 | USA         |
+----+-------------+
| 02 | Equador     |
+----+-------------+
| 03 | Perù        |
+----+-------------+
| 04 | Etc.        |
+----+-------------+
```

How can I generate multiple pages like example above?

Thanks

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to combine the DataSets into one. There's clearly already a relationship.

Comment: Hi Matt. How can I have more pages with one DataSet?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like combining the two datasets into one and then grouping on continent would work.  You can then set a page break after each continent to produce the output you're looking for.

In the group properties select the option to break "Between each instance of a group."

Answer (score 0):

Join the datasets together in TSQL

```
Select ContinentId = c.ContinentId ,
       Continent = c.Name,
       CountryId = country.CountryId,
       CountryName = Country.Name
From       Contintent c
Inner Join Country on Country.ContinentId = c.ContinentId
```

Add a table (or tablix) to your design surface.  Assign the above data set to your table.

Right click on the details group, Add Group | Parent Group
[image]

Group by ContinentId
[image]

Click OK

Now go to group properties (of parent group) and Set the page break

[image]

Will produce the following output.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the need for a report that was 4 pages long per each row in Dataset (read: 66 rows, 66 4-page reports). No rows needed to be displayed, just lots of textboxes with values all over the place on all 4 pages from the dataset row.
I added a Tablix control, and deleted the header row and all the columns in the details row. Then I added a Rectangle to that row. Then I right clicked on the left side of the Details row and added a Parent Group Row that grouped on my row's unique ID (in this case, Client ID). Then I went into Group Properties and checked Page Breaks "Between Each Instance of a Group". This was thanks to info in @Trubs answer above.

I made the first rectangle the size of a page more or less (10in, .5in margins) and clicked on the left border and picked "Insert Row, Inside Group Below". Boom. That was my next page. However, just touching that row causes a TextBox to pop into and take the row's shape so you can write something. All fine and dandy, but I had a bunch of textboxes I needed to set up. So, very carefully, I made sure the TextBox was highlighted and right clicked > Deleted it. And then very carefully I went over to tool box and added a Rectangle. Set the Rectangle to page size more or less, and added my various textboxes.

I repeated this for 2 more pages. Always double checking by previewing to make sure they printed out 2 sided (which is a printer setting.) 
I looked at each Rectangle property that I used to outline each page and the option "Keep contents together on same page if possible" was checked, which is probably why everything didn't go "sprong" and add extra blank pages. Not sure, but I wasn't too precise about any page breaks anywhere else but what I have outlined above.

I hope this helps someone. Sometimes you don't need a detail section with a bunch of rows of data. This was my solution to generate a 4-page report with each row's data all over the 4-pages. The Tablix was bound to the Dataset.